# NodeJS standalone cookie object in without http res

Tags: node.js, cookies

I am trying to write tests for an app that uses cookies for login. I want to create the cookies and return them to the test function. In this context, there is no http 'res' object.

Is there a way to create a standalone cookie object without using the http response 'res' object?

I've looked into the [set-cookie-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/set-cookie-parser) module but it appears to only be able to parse cookies from an existing res object.

Here is the code:

```
const getTestCookies = async(user) => {

  const jwt = exampleCtrl.getJwt(user);
  const cookieOptions = exampleCtrl.getCookieOptions();
  // THERE IS NO 'RES' OBJECT IN THIS CONTEXT BECAUSE IT IS NOT AN HTTP REQUEST
  const cookies = res.cookie('test-cookie', jwt, cookieOptions);

  return cookies;

}
```